# Python 3 - Displaying list in a particular order

Tags: python

If i have a list like:

```
L = [1,2,3,2,4,1,5]
```

How do i ask python to display the list in the following order:

```
L = [2,2,3,1,1,4,5]
```

If the list is constant can i define a particular order so that whenever my code generates a list similar to L it will be in my specified order.

Comment: So whats your logic behind this order?

Comment: Are you just grouping identical elements?

Comment: @Kasra I have no logic behind this order. I was just wondering if i can define a particular order for the list to follow other than the ascending or descending etc..

Comment: @hmm well yeah... if you have some logic in place to describe how you want to transform the list... At the moment... you can just use `L = [2,2,3,1,1,4,5]` and you're done...

Comment: If you are looking to hard code an order of elements, you can define it in a list that way, the elements of a list will maintain the order.

Comment: @khajvah I am trying to define a particular order. no grouping, ascending or descending..

Comment: @hmm Aha, if you dont have any logic so you need `random` function :D!

Comment: @hmm well... either hardcode the order... or describe what your "particular" order is...

Comment: If you want to define an arbitrary order, you can just hard-code a `set` and then check if a `set` of the resulting list matches your defined `set`.

Comment: is this what you're thinking of: `sorted(L, key=[2, 3, 1, 4, 5].index)`

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 sets do not maintain the order of insertion. The order is same once the set has been built, but the elements of the set will not necessarily be in the order of insertion.

Comment: The point is that the order doesn't matter. The asker wants to give a certain order to any `list` "similar" to a defined one. Just check if all the necessary elements are present. If the `list` has to be pretty much just a shuffled copy of the defined list (duplicates included), more checks would be needed. The question is kind of vague.

Comment: About all you could do is write something that could put an arbitrary list with exactly those elements in it into that order...which seems rather useless. Do you have a use case or are you just asking hypothetical questions for the heck of it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going on a hunch here, but when you write *"whenever my code generates a list similar to L it will be in my specified order."*, the following comes to mind;

```
order = [1,3,2,0,5,4,6]
L = [1,2,3,2,4,1,5]
Lnew = [L[i] for i in order]
```

At that point, `Lnew` is `[2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4, 5]`. The `order`-list basically lists the indices of the elements to retrieve, in a specific order.